# I'm unable to identify the last character in this picture

Tags: orthography, kana

[image]

I'm unable to identify the last character in this picture, OCR software identify only the first 2.

Answer (score 3):

The last character in that picture is ぞ (ZO).

Comment: Thanks, that means there is no UNICODE assignation for that specific variation.

Comment: In general Unicode does not assign new code points for stylistic variations of the same 'character'.